# code create multidimensional array instead of a 2d array in php whats going on here?

Tags: php, mysql

this code is written for adding an array comes from an ajax request, but instead of adding to a different array it save variable something like `a[0][0][1]` i know where i am writing wrong code `$olddata+$data`

```
if(isset($_GET["cmd"]))
{
    switch($_GET["cmd"]) 
    {
    case "addrolls":
         if($_POST["addrolls"]!="")
         {
            $data =json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['addrolls']));
            if(!isset($_SESSION['rollnumbers']))
                $_SESSION['rollnumbers']=$data
           else {
                $olddata=$_SESSION['rollnumbers'];
                $_SESSION['rollnumbers']=$olddata+$data;
           }
        }
        break;
    default:
        $engine_session->headerin();
        break;
    }
}else{
    $engine_session->headerin();
}
```

Comment: You are misssing `{` with your `if` condition?

Comment: Explain more what do u want. And use correct code formatting

Comment: @variables are not clear, and explanation needs to be improved!

Comment: have you tried  array_merge instead of '+' ?

Comment: Could you put the output you get in the end and in which variable it's stored ? There is no way to understand what exactly you are doing, and expecially what you are **trying** to achieve, if we don't know what exactly is in the parameters you use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shall format the code you sent in here and have a look over it.
You're missing semicolons and you should use braces after your if statement.

What is in $_SESSION['rollnumbers'] and what is the content of $data ?

We need more input to help you fixing your problem. Have you ever tried "array_merge_recursive"?

Please let us know the contents of $data, your session etc. - so we can check what's wrong.

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Note: Single line IF statements dont need to be in `{}` Its ugly and bad practice in my opinion, but not an illegal statement

Answer (score 0):

From you question I think you want to merge arrays of old and new. For it try this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["cmd"]))
{
  switch($_GET["cmd"]) 
  {
    case "addrolls":
      if($_POST["addrolls"]!="")
      {
        $data =json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['addrolls']),true); //<----to get array pass second param as trie
        if(!isset($_SESSION['rollnumbers']))
          $_SESSION['rollnumbers']=$data;
        else{
          $olddata=$_SESSION['rollnumbers'];
          $_SESSION['rollnumbers']=array_merge_recursive($olddata,$data); //<----- for merging array
        }
      }
    break;
    default:
      $engine_session->headerin();
    break;
  }
}
else
{
  $engine_session->headerin();
}
```

Comment: Array ids starts from 0 for all arrays, so merger of arrays not working bcz it just union my previous array.

Comment: `array_merge_recursive` will merge all values

Comment: is there any way to get $_session['rollnumbers'] has values like this (array1, array2, array3... etc) i have to input multiple arrays in session variable rollnumbers